# Android program stops working after a few uses

Tags: java, android

I made my first Android Java program, conversion between celsius and fahrenheit. This works good at first, but after a few conversions it won't convert them. If I change the values and press the button, it won't update the fields.

Here's the code.

```
package fi.peltoset.mikko.celfahr;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Celfahr extends Activity {
  private double celsius = 0.0;
  private double fahrenheit = 0.0;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button celsiusasteiksi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.celsiusasteiksi);
    Button fahrenheiteiksi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheitasteiksi);

    celsiusasteiksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)
                    findViewById(R.id.fahrenheitkentta)).getText().toString());         
          ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.celciuskentta)).setText(
                   String.valueOf(pyorista((fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8)));
        }
     });

     fahrenheiteiksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           celsius = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.celciuskentta))  
                    .getText().toString());     
           ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheitkentta))
                    .setText(String.valueOf(pyorista(celsius * 1.8 + 32)));
         }
    });
  }    

  double pyorista(double d) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(d));
  }
}
```

Sorry about bad language there (Finnish, heh...).

Comment: Where do you put the input text (the value you wanna convert)?

Comment: For your own sanity, it would be alot easier to setup your edittext's in oncreate and then reference them rather than finding the view each time. Like you have already done for the buttons

Comment: The EditText fields gettin reinitialised on every click. Might be related to the problem. could you try use them as fields and initialise them once before you set the listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, and others, suggest this for starters:

```
public class Celfahr extends Activity {
    private double celsius = 0.0;
    private double fahrenheit = 0.0;
    private EditText celsiuskentta;
    private EditText fahrenheitkentta;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button celsiusasteiksi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.celsiusasteiksi);
        Button fahrenheiteiksi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheitasteiksi);
        celsiuskentta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.celciuskentta);
        fahrenheitkentta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fahrenheitkentta)

        celsiusasteiksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(fahrenheitkentta.getText().toString());         
                celsiuskentta.setText(String.valueOf(pyorista((fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8)));
            }
        });

        fahrenheiteiksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                celsius = Double.parseDouble(celsiuskentta.getText().toString());   
                fahrenheitkentta.setText(String.valueOf(pyorista(celsius * 1.8 + 32)));
            }
        });
    }    
...
```

Also DecimalFormat returns a formatted String, so you don't need to convert the results from `pyorista()` to a double and back to a String. Sorry if I spelled any Finnish words wrong, hope this helps.

Comment: @Keyser Agreed, but I wasn't going to rewrite the _whole_ app, only eliminate the extraneous `findViewById()`. Showing is better than describing sometimes.

Comment: I shouldn't celebrate before I've tested it on a real Android device: The emulator runs it fine but when I send it to my HTC One S (4.0.3) it won't work. It works as my code in the original post.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try putting Log statements in the onClick() functions and pyorista() to determine where the problem is.